# Is there a way to use JS rest syntax in react hook dependencies array?

Tags: reactjs, rest, dependencies, react-hooks

I have this useEffect React hook :

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    api.post(url, state)
        .then(response => {
            setState(
                ...state,
                response: response.data
            )
        })
}, []);
```

that use a state as a payload for API request, and update `state` with the response.

Obviously, if I put `state` in hook dependencies array, we have an infinite loop (because `state` update after API call), but I need to call API and update `state.response` every time state changes.

Is it possible to update when `state` values changes, except for `state.response` ?

I tried :

```
const {response, ...rest} = state;
```

and put `rest` inside dependencies but that does not work

Thank you for your help

Comment: You have state in the `state` variable that you post the the backend and the backend responds with the same state? Sounds like you need split that state up into a) what you want to show/modify in that component and b) what you want to send to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState({
    apiParam: {},
    response: null
  });

useEffect(() => {
    api.post(url, state.apiParam)
        .then(response => {
            setState(state=>({
                ...state,
                response: response.data
             })    
            )
        })
}, [state.apiParam]);
```